# Script Karaf shell commands?

Tags: shell, scripting, apache-karaf, karaf

I need to issue Karaf shell commands non-interactively, preferably from a script. More specifically, I need to tell Karaf to `feature:install` a set of features in an automated way.

```
# Attempt to install a feature in a way I could script
bash> bin/karaf feature:install myFeature
# Drops me into Karaf shell
karaf> feature:uninstall myFeature
Error executing command: Feature named 'myFeature' is not installed
# Feature wasn't installed
```

Is this possible? Is there a different way of solving this issue (automated install of a set of Karaf features) that I'm missing?

Answer (score 5):

With bin/karaf you start Karaf with a login prompt, if you want to start Karaf so you can issue commands you first need to start Karaf in server mode. For this use the bin/start shell script. Now you can use either the bin/client or the bin/shell commands to communicate with Karaf in a headless mode.

For example:

```
./bin/client list
START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 50
ID | State  | Lvl | Version | Name
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
72 | Active |  80 | 0       | mvn_org.ops4j.pax.web.samples_war_4.1.0-SNAPSHOT_war
```

This should work for all versions of Karaf already (maybe not the 2.2.x line ;-) )
If the version you're using is a 3.0.x or higher you might need to add a user to the command.

```
./bin/client -u karaf list
```

Comment: I'm seeing a `Failed to get the session` error, but that's likely a different issue. Thanks for the info!

Comment: looks like you'll need a user with the client. In that case try with -u 'user'. Don't know which user ODL is using though, but can easily be found in the users.properties file in the etc folder.

Comment: `karaf = karaf,_g_:admingroup` seems to be the relevant line. Still seeing `Failed to get the session.` using `./bin/client -u karaf list`.

Comment: This is a "bit" late to respond but I'm thinking that others will find this answer useful. I had the same error pop up even with "-u karaf" and what solved it for me was adding "-h localhost"

Comment: Also a late response... just wanted to mention to be sure you are calling bin/start before connecting to the client. After that, sometimes it takes 10 seconds (or more) to start up.

Comment: @dfarrell07 same problem, it seems that you have to wait some unpredictable amount of time after issuing each karaf command, I've started new question because of it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43066208/how-to-detect-if-karaf-is-ready-to-accept-commands-via-client

Answer (score 5):

To issue Karaf shell commands not-interactively, preferably from  a script you can also use [the Karaf client (scroll down to "Apache Karaf client")](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/remote). To install features I use command like

```
/opt/karaf/bin/client -r 7 "feature:install http; feature:install webconsole"
```

The `-r` switch allows to retry the connection if the server is not up yet (I use it in a Docker script).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to issue non-interactive Karaf shell commands using sshpass if keeping the password secrete isn't important.

```
sshpass -p karaf ssh -tt -p 8101 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no karaf@localhost feature:install odl-l2switch-switch-ui
```

Working example in [OpenDaylight's Vagrant-based L2Switch Tutorial](https://github.com/opendaylight/integration-packaging/blob/master/tutorials/l2switch/Vagrantfile#L58).

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but this problem can easily be solved using the Features Boot configuration, located in the `etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg` file.

According to the following link https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/provisioning

> A boot feature is automatically installed by Apache Karaf, even if it has not been previously installed using feature:install or FeatureMBean.

There are 2 main properties of this file, the `featuresRepositories` and `featuresBoot`.

> - featuresRepositories contains a list (comma-separated) of features repositories (features XML) URLs.
> - featuresBoot contains a list (comma-separated) of features to install at boot.

Note that once you update this file, Karaf will attempt to install the features listed in the `featuresBoot` configuration every time it starts. So if all you are looking to automate is installing features (as per the original question), then this is a great option.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Expect.

[This Expect script from OpenDaylight's CI](https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/gitweb?p=releng/builder.git;a=blob;f=jjb/packaging/test-karaf.expect;h=fcbfaf64794971485ba70b4dd9f621cfa321738e;hb=refs/heads/master) installs and verifies a Karaf feature. Here's an excerpt:

```
# Install feature
expect "$prompt"
send "feature:install odl-netvirt-openstack\r"
expect {{
  "Error executing command: Can't install feature" {{
    send_user "\nFailed to install test feature\n"
    exit 1
  }}
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

So the general practice is to install the feature, then loop on a bundle:list | grep bundleName to see if the bundles you need are installed. Then you continue on with your test case.

Comment: this might be generally helpful info when dealing with karaf, but it is not an answer to the question (how to non interactively issue commands to karaf)